# SQL server 2008 R2 connection error / android

Tags: java, sql, connection

I have a problem with making connection to local SQL server 2008 R2,

here is code:

```
System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
            Connection conn = null;
            String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.2.101:1433/INSERTGT";
            String dbName = "podmiot";
            String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";


            String userName = "user"; 
            String password = "pass";
            try {
              Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
              conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
              System.out.println("Connected to the database");
              int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;


              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to the database", duration);

              conn.close();
              System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
              EditText edit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
              edit1.setText("Disconnected from database");

            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              TextView edit1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.exception);
              edit1.setText("Problem: " + e.toString());
            }
```

ERROR:

when I try to make connection I get error: `java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: localhost/127.0.0.1:1433 - connection refused.`

Sorry for my english... :)
Thx for help

Comment: is there a firewall that might block the traffic on that port?

Comment: You may not want your username / password in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your server allow remote connections?

http://forums.asp.net/t/1338911.aspx

Comment: I am not sure, becouse I downloaded this program ( sql management studio) and I cant even use it as it's written in Your link... but I also found on the other site how to do it in regedit, and it looks like I have all fine, :/

Comment: It sounds like you might not have the correct software.  You might try these links just to make sure you have the server.  The management studio is just used to connect to the server.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb671149